# Create binary variable based on number of unique / distinct values by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, split-apply-combine

I have data as follows:

```
userID  <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
product <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c","a","b","c")
df <- data.frame(userID, product)
```

For each 'userID', I want to create a binary indicator variable which is 1 if there are more than one unique product, and 0 if all products are the same.

so my filled vector would look like:

```
df$result <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
#    userID product result
# 1      1       a      0
# 2      1       a      0
# 3      1       a      0
# 4      2       b      1
# 5      2       b      1
# 6      2       c      1
# 7      3       a      1
# 8      3       b      1
# 9      3       c      1
```

E.g. user 1 has only one distinct product ('a') -> result = 0. User 2 has more than one unique product ('b' and 'c') -> result = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ave` from `base R`

```
 df$result <- with(df, ave(as.character(product), userID, 
                 FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))>1) +0 
 df$result
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Or as suggested by @David Arenburg, you could use `transform` and create a new variable `result` within the `df`

```
  transform(df, result = (ave(as.character(product), 
          userID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))>1)+0)
```

Or

```
tbl <- rowSums(!!table(df[,-3]))>1
(df$userID %in% names(tbl)[tbl])+0
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Ah you solved me the mystery of why I couldn't make `ave` work, `as.character`... So annoying

Comment: @David Arenburg I also got the warning.  But, then I thought about `as.character` or perhaps `as.numeric` would also fit

Comment: You could also maybe add a similar solution using `transform`, something like `transform(df, result = ave(as.character(product), userID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1) + 0))`

Comment: The one I got working was
`tbl <- rowSums(!!table(df[,-3]))>1`
with the second command line changed to:
`(df$userID %in% names(tbl)[tbl])+0`

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to achieve this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := as.integer(uniqueN(product) > 1), by = userID]
# or
# setDT(df)[, result := as.integer(length(unique(product)) > 1), by = userID]
df
#    userID product result
# 1:      1       a      0
# 2:      1       a      0
# 3:      1       a      0
# 4:      2       b      1
# 5:      2       b      1
# 6:      2       c      1
# 7:      3       a      1
# 8:      3       b      1
# 9:      3       c      1
```

---

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(userID) %>%
  mutate(result = as.integer(n_distinct(product) > 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use packages `data.table` or `dplyr` to solve this kind of split-apply-combine task. This is how you could do it using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)    ## convert to the new format
df[, result:=as.integer(length(unique(product)) > 1), by=userID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine:

```
# table of users x number_of_products
myTable <- table(userID, product)
# one line from there:
(result <- ifelse(rowSums(myTable!=0)==1, 0, 1)[userID])
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```